# How to relate a function to a specific netCDF file based on timestamp

Tags: r, function, raster, netcdf, netcdf4

I have 73 netCDF files each representing 5 day intervals of a calendar year and have several variables. Each file has 120 layers representing hourly intervals.

I have read them all into R and named them appropriately using the `ncdf4` package like so:

```
filenames <- list.files(path=getwd()) 

for(i in filenames) {
  ncin <- nc_open(i)
  ds<-paste(i)
  assign(ds, ncin)
  print(i)
  }
```

I also have a data frame of locations in the same projection as the netCDF files (lat-lon) however these locations irregularly span the entire calendar year as well. A sample of the data looks like this:

```
>head(df)
> Lon      Lat            datetime
2 -3.179046 58.65417 2016-09-30 17:25:38
3 -3.180403 58.65483 2016-09-30 17:29:43
4 -3.187734 58.66102 2016-09-30 21:22:51
5 -3.190197 58.66409 2016-09-30 22:02:47
6 -3.182058 58.67433 2016-10-01 06:16:08
7 -3.181318 58.67475 2016-10-01 06:20:31
```

What I am trying to do is to match the data-frame to the correct netCDF file and layer based on it's datetime stamp i.e. if it's between day 1 and 5 of the year it would be netCDF file 1 etc.. then I want to interpolate the variable data from the netCDF file onto the location data with associated datetime stamp of the data frame. So at the given time and place provided by the data-frame, what is the value of variable V at the same date and time in the netCDF file. I can do the first part using loop functions but it's grossly inefficient and time consuming to code:

```
function(dataframe){
d <- dataframe[i,]
if(between(d$datetime, 2017-01-01 00:00:00, 2017-01-05 23:59:59){ncfile <- file1} else if (between(d$datetime, 2017-01-06 00:00:00, 2017-01-010 23:59:59)) 
     {ncfile <- file2}}
```

And so on... Having never worked with netCDF files before I'm unsure as to the best method. Any suggestions?

################# UPDATE

I read the netCDF files in using

```
filenames <- list.files(path=getwd()) 
x <- lapply(filenames, nc_open)
```

extract dates from the file which are sequentially named:

```
PFOW_Climatology2_0001_1993-01-01.nc
PFOW_Climatology2_0002_1993-01-06.nc
```

up to

```
PFOW_Climatology2_0073_1993-12-27.nc
```

by using

```
fd <- as.Date(substr(filenames, 24, 36))
```

I then create a reference column for the dataframe by find9ing the interval within which each data point corresponds in fd like so:

```
i <- findInterval(dd, fd) 
df$file <- i
```

Answer (score 2):

It is very difficult to give a good answer without you providing more information, and ideally some example data.

Your "appropriate naming" is highly inappropriate. You really should not need  `assign` in daily life. Just make a list.

```
library(ncdf4)
x <- lapply(filenames, nc_open)
```

But since you need to extract values by location, it is perhaps better to make a list of RasterBrick objects:

```
library(raster)
x <- lapply(filenames, brick)
```

But I would not do that either.

I would first match the file names with df$datetime. As you do not tell us what the file names look like, I cannot tell you how to do that. But you won't need a loop. Extract the dates from the filenames, create an appropriate date (and time?) object and do something like

```
fd <- as.Date(subtr(filenames, 4, 12))
dd <- as.Date(df$datetime)
i <- which(dd > fd[-length(fd)] & dd < fd[-1]) + 1 

df$file <- filenames[i]
df$id <- 1:nrow(df)
```

Now you can loop over the filenames and extract the values:

```
ff <- unique(df$file)
vv <- sapply(ff, function(f) {
         v <- extract(brick(f), df[df$file == f , c('lon', 'lat')])
         data.frame(file=f, xy, v)
      })
```

`vv` should be a data.frame with values for each case, for its corresponding 5-day interval. From there select (or interpolate) the time you want from the 120 values.

I assume that you want to do temporal interpolation. For (also) spatial interpolation use `method = 'bilinear'` in `extract`

Again, this may not work, as I do not have example data. But something along these lines will work.

Comment: Thank you @RobertH. I have amended the question to include more information and updated to include the most recent suggestions you made which were very helpful. I couldn't get your {which} function to work so I used 'findInterval' instead.

Comment: I'm however not sure how your function should work. If you try to brick a ncdf4 object you get an error: 'unable to find an inherited method for function ‘raster’ for signature ‘"ncdf4"'

Comment: `brick` should be used on the filename, not on a ncdf4 object